# curiosity about tag characters inside tag ""

Tags: html, forms

I would like to understand why using a browser, and editing an html page with the inspect button, the value fields of the radio inputs cannot be changed with;

```html
value='"'
```

I change the character to & quot;

value="""

because chrome firefox and others do not allow to insert the character " clean within the value?
can you give me an explanation on this?

Comment: Can you provide more context to your question, possibly show a code snippet of the radio inputs?

Comment: hello mine is a generic question, there is no code, I just want to understand why by inspecting element in any form the character inside the tag value = "text" cannot be changed to value = 'text'

Answer (score 0):

The inspector favors double quotes to clearly show strings. It may not actually look that way in the DOM, but in the inspector it's the rule. You can't have an unescaped double quote in-between 2 others, so `value="\""` might work, or `value="&quot;"` as you said. Not sure how relevant [this link is](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/81fbdf7119fad8035274e3df409ca76572685bf3/devtools/client/shared/components/reps/reps/rep-utils.js#142-174) but it shows that they purposely hard-code that double quote in there

Comment: but why can't I insert value= ' " '?

Comment: chrome inpector rewrites values (only in the inspector) to be enclosed in double-quotes

Comment: you know if there is a way to insert the character " inside the value that is not &quot;?

Comment: I realized that even writing a form in an html editor file, it transforms me value = '"' into value = '& quot;', you know some browser that does not allow this change on the code

Comment: Won't this work? `value="\"this is inside a quote\""`

Comment: change it to \ & quot;this is inside a quote \ &quot;

Comment: it changes me* sorry